# Thymeleaf - I can't pass two values from HTML to Controller using Link th:href

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot.
I have a link in my html using thymeleaf:

```
 <a th:href="@{/fleetcompany/workorders/proposals/selected/{id}(id=${proposal.bidID})/{id2}(id2=${proposal.workID})}">SELECT</a>
```

When I only pass one value, it works but when I pass two values, it didn't. It has errors:

```
  Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}(id=${proposal.bidID})"
```

This is my MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/workorders/proposals/selected/{bidID}/{woNumber}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String selectProposal(Model model,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        @PathVariable("bidID") Long bidID,
        @PathVariable("woNumber") Long woNumber){

    String selected = "Selected";
    String notSelected = "Not Selected";
    String orderStatus = "Pending";
    bidServiceInterface.updateSelectedBidStatus(selected, bidID);
    bidServiceInterface.updateNotSelectedBidStatus(notSelected, woNumber);
    woServiceInterface.updateWorkOrderStatus(orderStatus, woNumber);
    return "redirect:/fleetcompany/workorders";
}
```

I know all my datatypes are correct, because when I interchanged both ids it worked but not when I use them both together.

Comment: When you get the error, what is the actual url it is using?  I also wonder if the path variable when you have /selected/1234/1234 is translating to 1234/1234 thus, it's not able to convert to long.  could you try /selected/1234/workorder/1234?

Comment: Just tried it in an example project and having two path variables next to each other works fine for me.  Makes me think there is something in with the numbers that should be there.  Can you post the URL it's going to?

Comment: @blur0224 I solved it. I didn't know the i have to do it with one initializer only. Like this. <a th:href="@{/fleetcompany/workorders/proposals/selected/{id}/{id2}(id=${proposal.bidID}, id2=${proposal.woNumber})}">SELECT</a>. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Lester: You can write up what you did as an answer and then accept it, so that future people can learn as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. I didn't know that i have to do it with one initializer only. Like this.

```
<a th:href="@{/fleetcompany/workorders/proposals/selected/{id}/{id2}(id=${proposal.‌​bidID}, id2=${proposal.woNumber})}">SELECT</a>.
```